# Check if a location exists in a route in Map API

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapbox

I'm using MapBox iOS SDK for showing route between two locations. I would like to know if there is any possibility to check whether a location lies in a route.

I need this functionality so that if any incident happen one location and if that location lies in the route, I need to alert the user about this and need to show the alternate route.

For e.g.:- Say I have plotted a route between location A and location B. I want to check if location C lies in the route between A and B. Any suggestion from MapBox Api or google maps Api is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a list of coordinate from mapbox route, then i think calculate distance from points to your interested point. it can yield an acceptable result

Comment: Coudl you elaborate your answer a bit further?

Comment: But I think this approach is a costly one because we are trying to calculate the distance of each waypoint with another location and then deriving the result.

Comment: there is a function in google maps call: isLocationOnEdge or few similar function in GMSGeometryUtils, but no such thing in mapbox, so i think we should just calculate the distance to coordinate in the route data, there is an class intersection in mapbox api, check if it help you check a point belong to an intersection.